# Accessing public methods from a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control with this simple public method:

```
public void appendHtml(string html)
{
    txtTinyMce.InnerText += html;
}
```

In the page where this control is contained, I have specified it in the page's markup like so:

```
<QuickBuck:TinyMCE runat="server" ID="tinyMCE" />
```

When I call `tinyMCE.appendHtml`, it doesn't find it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That should work fine, I do it in my code with no issues. Where are you trying to call appendHtml, in the markup or code-behind? Do you have a definition defined for that control in the designer? Are you getting a compile error or runtime error?

Comment: It is a compile error and I was calling it in the code-behind.I said `was` because I created a property to substitute which is working fine.

Comment: As Brian said, it should work fine.  I've had issues before in Visual Studio with Custom Controls not being recognized properly.  Sometimes cleaning the solution or project, then rebuilding fixes it.

Comment: I tried rebuilding it still didn't work. Who knows what happened :/

Comment: Could you please post the line of code you use to register the user control at page level?